# Table user control not displaying

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a usercontrol that would only contain a table but the table does not appear, it only says "System.Windows.Documents.Table".

I am creating the user control and putting a table in it like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.TestTableControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Table>
    <Table.Columns>
        <TableColumn/>
        <TableColumn/>
        <TableColumn/>
    </Table.Columns>
    <!-- Header -->
    <TableRowGroup>
        <TableRow FontWeight="Bold">
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>Head1</Paragraph>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>Head2</Paragraph>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>Head3</Paragraph>
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>1</Paragraph>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>2</Paragraph>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>3</Paragraph>
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableRowGroup>
</Table>
```

And then from my test project, i am calling my control like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<my:TestTableControl/>
```

Nothing very special here, but when i build the solution, the only result i get is this:
[image: Running Program]

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you have in your .cs file ?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. It's pure xaml so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.Windows.Documents.Table`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) cannot be hosted with the results you expect by just any container (`UserControl` in your case). That is why it just calls the `ToString()` method for displaying purposes, resulting in the string you see.

Look into the remarks section of the [`Table`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. It lists suitable parental containers for the `Table`. `Table` is for document like structures.

If you want to display ordered data in a grid structure [`DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be a suitable solution instead.

If you just want to layout your form with a table-like structure to put other controls in, the [`Grid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class will be what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh ok, you're right DataGrid would be a much more useful block to use in my case. It looks like the Table does not exactly act as I wanted it to, reading the notes here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747133%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, it seems that the Table should only be used within a FlowDocument